# How to make C# web service produce soapenv namespace instead of soap?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

Is there a way to make a C#/.NET web service which normally produces XML like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
 <DHeader xmlns="http://www.abc.com" />
</soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Response xmlns="http://www.abc.com">
      <Result>
        <ErrorObject ObjectID="string" ErrorCode=""  />          
      </Result>
     </Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

to produce XML like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapv:Header>
    <DHeader xmlns="http://www.abc.com" />
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <Response xmlns="http://www.abc.com">
      <Result>
        <ErrorObject ObjectID="string" ErrorCode=""  />          
      </Result>
    </Response>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This trying solve a problem with an AXIS client consuming a .NET web service. AXIS is choking on the soap namespace and needs a soapenv namespace. Changing the AXIS side is not possible.

any thoughts or comments would be great.

Here is the exact error as requested.

```
line -1: Element Envelope@http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope is not a valid Envelope@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ document or a valid substitution.
```

Answer (score 1):

`soapenv` is not a namespace - it's a namespace prefix.

As long as the prefixes refer to the same namespace, `soap` and `soapenv` refer to the same thing, and have the identical meaning.

It seems extremely unlikely that any version of AXIS is so badly broken as to treat the prefixes specially. You should assume you have a different problem. Please post the exact error you're receiving.

Comment: This what they are getting. 

line -1: Element Envelope@http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope is not a valid Envelope@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ document or a valid substitution. 

Also thanks for the correction on the prefix namespace thing.

Comment: The XML you posted does not use the "w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" namespace. The XML you posted would not give you this error. Try sending the XML you posted here.

Comment: This means it is not possible at all??

Comment: It means there's no reason to do it, unless the consumer is badly broken.

Comment: That's OK, but I am keen to know, I achieved this using SoapExtension, modified outgoing SOAP message as per my requirement,  but it is the only way to do this?

Comment: Most likely it's the only way to do something that should make no sense. Any code that cares about the prefix is badly broken, fails to obey XML standards which have been in effect for over a decade, and should really be either fixed, or else the creator be put out of business.

Comment: So we are encouraged to use meaningful names but here we are stuck with s: and a:, how disappointing.

Comment: @aries nobody encouraged you to use meaningful namespace prefixes. It makes no sense.

Comment: @John Saunders Please explain or shoud I call you J:

Comment: @aries When you say "we are encouraged to use meaningful names", you mean things like variable names? Namespace prefixes aren't the same sort of thing. They are just an abbreviation for a long, namespace.